# Iterating through a directory and print the content of every file [PYTHON]

Tags: python, file, iteration

actually it must be simple but I just can't find the solution.

I've got a directory. Lets call it "files" containing txt-files (lycris2,lyrics)

I want to iterate over this directory and print out the content of every txt.file

So here is my code:

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir("files"):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    content = f.read()
    print(content)
```

But it's not working. Here is the error message I've been shown:

```
C:\Users\Juan\.virtualenvs\PyQT\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/Python Kurs/Kursmaterialien/PyQT/venvy library root/testmain.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/Python Kurs/Kursmaterialien/PyQT/venvy library root/testmain.py", line 4, in <module>
    f = open(filename, 'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lyrcis2'
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

File handler needs the full relative path from your current directory:

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir("files"):
    f = open(os.path.join("files", filename), 'r')
    content = f.read()
    print(content)
```

Comment: For best compatibility, you'll want to use os.path.join() instead of concatenating filename strings.  So, `open("files/"+filename, 'r')` should become `open(os.path.join("files", filename), 'r')`  Also, note that that's not the complete file path, it's the relative path from your script's current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3 users there's [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```py
import pathlib

for path in pathlib.Path('files').iterdir():
    if not path.is_file():
        continue
    with path.open() as f:
        print(f.read())
```